# Complex gamma function in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

As I understand [from the doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_gamma/tgamma.html), the `tgamma` function of the `boost` C++ library can be evaluated for complex numbers.

I'm trying to use it in `Rcpp`. This is my code:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::complex<double> gamma_boost(std::complex<double> z) { 
  std::complex<double> result = tgamma(z);
  return result;
}
```

This code doesn't compile. I get the error:

```
cannot convert 'std::complex<double>' to 'double' for argument '1' to 'double tgamma(double)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have the wrong `tgamma()` here, try `boost::math::tgamma(...)`. And/or you may need to template on `std::complex`.

My usual approach is to get something to work first on the command-line, and then attach such code to R via Rcpp.

Comment: Indeed, stupid of me. My code does not work with `boost::math::tgamma` but this is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are calling the wrong function.

You didn't specify a namespace, so ADL finds [`std::tgamma`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tgamma) from the Standard Library due to `z`.

`std::tgamma` doesn't take `std::complex` as parameters, so you get a compiler error. You want `boost::math::tgamma` instead.

**But** Boost's `tgamma` also doesn't support `std::complex` types, so you'll need to use another library or implement it yourself.

Comment: You're right. Finally I don't need Rcpp: I can use the log-gamma function in the `gsl` package, which works for complex numbers.